# How to draw path along circle in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphics

I'd like to draw an arbitrary path along a circle (e.g. a sine wave or bezier curve) in Flutter using Custom Painter.

I'm looking for a way to transform this path with Matrix4 but can't find a proper way to do it.

Let's say that I start with a following layout:

[image]

And I would like to achieve following projection:

[image]

Please find the minimal starting example. I was trying to rotate `mpath` using Matrix transformation but couldn't come up with correct transformation. For instance:

```dart
final matrix = Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(0, 1, 2)
      ..rotateY(val * math.pi)
      ..translate(-120.0);
    canvas.transform(matrix.storage);
```

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: OnCriclePainter(),
    );
  }
}

class OnCriclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.saveLayer(null, Paint());

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    Path mpath = new Path();
    var val = 1.0;
    mpath.relativeQuadraticBezierTo(40, val * 100, 80, 0);
    mpath.relativeQuadraticBezierTo(40, -val * 100, 80, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(mpath, paint);

// how to place it onto the circle?

    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawCircle(
      Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
      size.width / 2,
      Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = 1
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
    );

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(OnCriclePainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use conicTo function like this :

```
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(x, y)
      ..conicTo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double w);
```

from doc :

Adds a bezier segment that curves from the current point to the given point (x2,y2), using the control points (x1,y1) and the weight w. If the weight is greater than 1, then the curve is a hyperbola; if the weight equals 1, it's a parabola; and if it is less than 1, it is an ellipse.

OR use quadraticBezierTo function

```
quadraticBezierTo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
```

this link is useful to understand quadraticBezierTo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ToqYMSnNhA